# is it possible to force Acrobat to save as PDF/A by default?

Tags: pdf, windows-registry, adobe-acrobat

Has anyone had experience forcing Adobe Acrobat to save created/edited/merged PDF's as PDF/A by default?

My workplace forces all PDF's to be saved as PDF/A, training the users to manually save each document in this format is possible but mistakes will happen. I'm trying to find a solution that streamlines the process for the end-user. We are currently using Foxit PhantomPDF and it allows you to change a registry key or change a setting which will force the default save type to whatever you'd like (I cannot remember if it is a registry key or setting, sorry).

Adobe support was not helpful.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is not an option to change the save-as default in Acrobat. If you're familiar with JS or VBA, then it looks like you can create a batch sequence to run `doc.SaveAs([path],[FiletypeID])`. See some docs here: https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/jsapiref/doc.html#saveas But that's probably a lot more involved than you're looking for.